# Bing Maps Infobox, with html view

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc-4, bing-maps

Is it possibel to load an _PartialView in ASP.Net MVC 4. I no that it's possibel to load it with the content

```
var defaultInfobox = new Microsoft.Maps.Infobox(map.getCenter(), infoboxOptions );    
 map.entities.push(defaultInfobox);
 defaultInfobox.setHtmlContent('<div id="infoboxText" style="background-color:White; border-style:solid;border-width:medium; border-color:DarkOrange; min-height:100px;width:240px;"><b id="infoboxTitle" style="position:absolute; top:10px; left:10px; width:220px;">myTitle</b><a id="infoboxDescription" style="position:absolute; top:30px; left:10px; width:220px;">Description</a></div>');
```

But i have not found any examples using an cshtml view.

Update:

```
 var pushpinOptions = { icon: '../images/BingMap/discussion-icon-ny.png', width: 30, height: 40 };
                    var latLon = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(location.latitude, location.longitude);
                    var pin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(latLon, pushpinOptions);
                    pin.Title = name;//usually title of the infobox
                    pin.Description = set; //information you want to display in the infobox
                    pinLayer.push(pin);//add pushpin to pinLayer
                    Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(pin, 'click', displayInfobox);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Step: Put your html in a partial view
2. Step: Install and Integrate JavaScriptModel ( http://jsm.codeplex.com )
3. Step: You need the following method in your Controller Base:

   ```
   public string RenderPartialViewAsString(string partialViewName, object model = null)
   {
       if (partialViewName == null)
           throw new ArgumentNullException("partialViewName");

       ViewDataDictionary viewData = new ViewDataDictionary(model);

       using (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter())
       {
           ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, partialViewName);

           if (viewResult == null || viewResult.View == null)
               throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Could not find partial view with name '{0}'", partialViewName));

           ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View, viewData, TempData, writer);
           viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, writer);

           return Regex.Replace(writer.ToString(), @"[\t\n\r]", string.Empty, RegexOptions.Compiled);
       }
   }
   ```
4. Step: Now you can add partial views to javascript variables anytime you want. E.g. you could write in your controller action:

   ```
   this.AddJavaScriptVariables("MyJavaScriptVariable", RenderPartialViewAsString("MyBingPartialView"));
   ```
5. Step: Edit your js.file:

   ```
   defaultInfobox.setHtmlContent(MyJavaScriptVariable);
   ```

Comment: Hello.Im not sure have to use the 'this.AddJavaScriptVariables("MyJavaScriptVariable", RenderPartialViewAsString("MyBingPartialView"));'. Where do need to put it ore use it.

Comment: http://jsm.codeplex.com - Check the documentation how to install and integrate it in your MVC project.

Comment: You are absolut correct. That's my fault :(. But i needed to change the code so i can display multiple push pins with infobox's. But i'm not sore have to implement your code with that. Please help.

Comment: On which step are you stuck?